How can I get both COUNTs to show up in one column?
I have one column named member_casual with two values. Either member or casual. What I'm looking for is a count of each value to populate in one column. When I use the query below (which I know isn't what will get me the exact results I'm looking for), they show up as two separate columns.
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN member_casual = 'casual' THEN 1 END) AS casual,
COUNT(CASE WHEN member_casual = 'member' THEN 1 END) AS member
FROM table
which results in



casual
member




1531839
2799921



What I'm trying to get is the count in one column as shown below



Row
member_casual




casual
1531839


member
2799921




You may aggregate by member_casual:
SELECT member_casual, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
WHERE member_casual IN ('casual', 'member')
GROUP BY member_casual;


This can be solved by using a count with an updated where clause and removing the case for each count.
Query the records using a where clause that filters either member or casual
SELECT count(*) as member_casual 
FROM tableName 
WHERE member_casual IN ('member', casual')


This returned the total count of member_casual. Maybe I did something wrong?

Its your filter parameters, you need to make sure you're filtering only on the records that match your criteria. Are all the records in that table either member or casual? If they are then it makes sense why you're getting the total count of the entire table
